# How to check status-code of URL of the application in protractor test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jasmine, protractor

I am using request package to request the url and using deferred promise :

```
getMonitoredPageName = function () {
    var deferredExecutor = protractor.promise.defer();
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();

    request('http://google.com',
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode ==400) {
            defer.reject(response.statusCode);
        } else {
            defer.fulfill(response.statusCode);
        }
    });

    return defer.promise;        
}
```

And i am calling above function from test as :

```
  it('should log the page name of every page view in the wizard', function () {

    // We opened the first page of the wizard and we expect it to have been logged
    expect(heartBeatNotification.getMonitoredPageName()).toBeTruthy(true);
    //expect(heartBeatNotification.getMonitoredPageName()).toBe(400);
    //browser.controlFlow().execute(heartBeatNotification.getMonitoredPageName);

})
```

Problem is test case always succeeds no matter what url has given. Need to write test case to check Application is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-zero status code will be "truthy" so you need to adjust your test case.  Make it check that the response is either explicitly 200, or maybe even just check thats its anything 2xx because that's still successful.

```
expect(heartBeatNotification.getMonitoredPageName()).toEqual(200);
```

Or just check that its greater than 200 or less than 300 etc.

```
expect(heartBeatNotification.getMonitoredPageName()).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(200);
expect(heartBeatNotification.getMonitoredPageName()).toBeLessThan(300);
```

Also, minor note, you might want to review the logic on your first `if` block.

```
    if (error || response.statusCode ==400) {
        defer.reject(response.statusCode);
    }
```

If there was an error, there might not be a `response.statusCode` (not positive).  Might be better to just reject with the error itself

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the test working this way. It's a little simplified over what you were trying to do but it should help you figure it out. One thing to note, the way you have your if block setup has issues. If `response` is `undefined` the test will timeout and the promise will never return. Anyhow, here is how I was able to get your test working.

```
it('should return status code 200', async () => {
    const url = 'http://google.com';
    await heartBeatNotification.getMonitoredPageName(url).then(statusCode => {
        expect(statusCode).toEqual(200);
    }, () => {
        fail('app not started');            
    });
});
```

Here is the function:

```
getMonitoredPageName = (url) => {
    const defer = protractor.promise.defer();

    request(url, (err, response, body) => {            
        if(err) {
            defer.reject();
        } else {
            defer.fulfill(response.statusCode);
        }
    });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: it is working for public site. My site is within intranet, response is undefined

Comment: Also if i send url as http://googleasdasdasd.com then the function is waiting for the response for long time.

Comment: I made some changes to the if block. Try that and see if it is working. Should be better now.